# Is this how `hoisting` work in JS?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Is my assumptions are correct about following code:

Here is the code:

```
1   var foo = 1;
2       if (true) {
3           var foo = 10;
4       }
5       console.log(foo);
```

`var` on `line 3` and `1` is `hoisted` to top and code becomes:

```
1   var foo;
2   foo = 1;
3       if (true) {
4           foo = 10;
5       }
6       console.log(foo);
```

Is this understanding right? Is this how `hoisting` work in JS?

Actually first I `hoisted` `var` on `line 3` but then I had to `hoist` the one which was on `line 1`, cause it was declaration and was no longer on the top.

Comment: Yes, this is how hoisting works.  Since you know the term "hoisting" a simple search for "Javascript hoisting" would have given you tons of articles and answers here on StackOverflow to read as this is well discussed topic.  I will now find a duplicate here on StackOverflow to mark this.

Comment: I think CodeSchool's JavaScript Road Trip covers hoisting quite well, but I don't remember which part.